# Requestanimationframe polyfill argument

Tags: javascript, function, polyfills

I have 2 questions regarding the requestanimationframe polyfill function:

1)Why was `element` included as an argument in `window.requestAnimationFrame=function(callback, element)`?

2)Why was 16 used here: `var timeToCall =Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));`? Is it up to the programmer judgement, not too big nor too low since we are subracting currTime-lastTime from it?

```
(function() {
    var lastTime =0;
    var vendors=['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
    for(var x=0; x<vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame=window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
        window.cancelAnimationFrame =
        window[vendors[x]+ 'CancelAnimationFrame'] ||
        window[vendors[x] +'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
    }
    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
    window.requestAnimationFrame=function(callback, element) {
        var currTime =new Date().getTime();
        var timeToCall =Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
        var id =window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime+timeToCall); },
        timeToCall);
        lastTime =currTime + timeToCall;
        return id;
    };
    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
    window.cancelAnimationFrame=function(id) {
        clearTimeout(id);
    };
}());
```

Comment: `element` is not used here and dont exists for the original `requestAnimationFrame` method according to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), 16 = 1/60 -> 60 fps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by Hacketo, element is indeed not a parameter of the window.requestAnimationFrame, it only expects the callback function.

Secondly the 16 is used to determine a maximum FPS. The setTimeout function will not fire any faster than 60 times per second. This is however a fragile approach for game synchronization. [This article](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html) describes a great approach.